# How to determine Intel Celeron generation?

Tags: cpu, intel-celeron

I need to know the ordinal number of my Intel Celeron processor. Through the software CPU-Z, I can see my processor is Intel Celeron 3865U:

[image: CPU-Z]

When I google about it, they say the generation is the number after the **i** prefix in the processor name, but there is none in my case. I'm not sure how many left-to-right digits I've to consider. Any idea?

Comment: You already have the ordinal number of your *Celeron processor*. It is not a *Core* CPU.

Comment: @DanielB Sorry, I didn't get it. I got in the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Celeron_processors) and looks like they say it spans from sixth to eighth generations (I think). It doesn't tell the number of specific ones...

Comment: According to intel it is a 8th generation, see graphics processor graphic section>>>>https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/189309/intel-celeron-processor-4205u-2m-cache-1-80-ghz/specifications.html

Comment: Or https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/96507/intel-celeron-processor-3865u-2m-cache-1-80-ghz.html

Answer (score 2):

You have a 7th Generation "Kaby Lake" CPU. Celerons don't follow the same naming scheme as the other processors which make them more difficult to identify. CPU-Z is reporting it as a Kaby Lake-R (refresh) model, but that is incorrect as the R-series was launched in August of 2017 and yours was launched Q1 2017.

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/96507/intel-celeron-processor-3865u-2m-cache-1-80-ghz.html

Your processor still has some life in it as it supports Windows 10 but it does not support Windows 11.

Comment: It should be noted that the "life of a CPU" isn't determined by Windows versions becoming EoL. If that was the criteria this hardware would be obsolete no later than 2025 and the true is it can work acceptably for some years after that with any mainstream Linux distro.